# Test mail not sending in drupal 7 SMTP configuration in windows 2012 server

Tags: 7, emails

I installed and configured smtp module with proper details in drupal 7. I tried to send test the mail in windows 2012 server but am getting the below error.

SMTP -> ERROR:

> Failed to connect to server: `php_network_getaddresses`: `getaddrinfo` failed: This is usually a temporary error during hostname resolution and means that the local server did not receive a response from an authoritative server.
>
> SMTP Error: Could not connect to SMTP host.
>
> Unable to send e-mail. Contact the site administrator if the problem persists.

[image: image1]

[image: image2]

Same build is working fine in Windows XP, 07 and ubuntu environments.

Not able to find the root cause. Any suggestions are welcome.

Comment: What's in your logs? Anything except "temporary error"?

Comment: check the firewall settings..

Comment: Thanks Rupesh,

May I know what should I check in firewall settings?

Comment: From my experience, GMail has not been working with port 25/TLS, and recently, it stopped working with SSL as well, unless your site runs under https.